# Titanium installation on Windows XP

Tags: installation, cross-platform, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I'm trying to build some apps in Titanium.

I have set the path for the Android SDK. Titanium detected it and showed the Android tab in Titanium.

But when I try to launch an application, I'm unable to load the Android SDK.

The "Trace" panel shows this data:

```
[TRACE] Traceback (most recent call last):
[TRACE] File "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.6.0\android\builder.py", line 10, in <module>
[TRACE] from compiler import Compiler
[TRACE] File "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.6.0\android\compiler.py", line 14, in <module>
[TRACE] from deltafy import Deltafy
[TRACE] File "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.6.0\android\deltafy.py", line 8, in <module>
[TRACE] import os, sys, platform, sqlite3, time, stat
[TRACE] File "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Titanium\modules\win32\python\1.0.0\lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
[TRACE] from dbapi2 import *
[TRACE] File "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Titanium\modules\win32\python\1.0.0\lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
[TRACE] from _sqlite3 import *
[TRACE] ImportError: DLL load failed: Invalid access to memory location.
```

And FYI I'm using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new project and (without modifying any of the automatically generated default code) try to launch it, does the Android SDK successfully load it?

If so, copy everything except the build directory from a project that doesn't work into the new default project. Does it work now?

This is what I (and, judging from Internet forums, a lot of other people) needed to do to get the Kitchen Sink app to run, for example.

Comment: i tried as you said but no use. The new peoject didnt created the build folder.

Comment: @Prateek: Which part didn't work?  Did you create a new default project and tried to launch it and it failed?  Or did that succeed? If it succeeded, did you copy everything except the build directory from the project that isn't working and that's when it failed?